# How do I add a gestureRecognizer to my GameScene.m file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to make a game and I want to be able to detect a swipes angle. I'm not really sure if I know how, but theres the part of my code where it gives me an error when trying to add a gestureRecognizer to the GameScene.m file.

```
 -(IBAction) someMethod {
     UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)];
     [panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
     [panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
     [GameScene addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
     [panRecognizer release]; }
```

On the 3rd line when I add it, it gives me the following error.:

```
No known class method for selector 'addGestureRecognizer:'
```

Do I have to import something for it to work? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think you should add (alloc) your gesture recognizer to your view. Or you can add it in the GameScene.m but in didMoveToView method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method addGestureRecognizer is a member of the UIView class -- so you need to call it from the SKScene view member.

So try this...

```
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your GameScene.m

```
- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)];
    [[self view] addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
}
```